# Dask: number of CPUs used for same computation drops over time

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

While using dask for decimating timeseries, I noticed that sometimes only 1-2 CPUs are used for the computation even though at other times CPU utilization is high (suggesting the algorithm is not the problem). I would like to know why the the drop in CPU use occurs and how I can make sure that the CPUs are utilized to the fullest every time.

The set up is the following: we have a (n,t) array (n=~400 and t=~50M timepoints) stored in a binary file that we wrap in a delayed memory-mapped dask array following the example [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-creation.html#memory-mapping). We then use `map_overlap` to apply `scipy.signal.decimate` to partially overlapping chunks of the data.

Next, I spin up a dask-scheduler and a single dask-worker (nprocs=1 and nthreads=10) in a jupyterhub instance on a single machine that has 32 cores and 256GB memory. In a jupyter notebook, I connect a client to the scheduler and run the same decimation computation multiple times.

In some instances, all works as expected and the CPU utilization is high. See snapshot of the CPU utilization below that shows high utilization for 5 executions of the same dask graph.

[image]

However in other instances, e.g. when I restart schedular/worker, CPU utilization is initially high, but drops such that only 1-2 CPUs are used, as seen in the snapshot with 3 executions of the same dask graph.

[image]

Comment: Could it be due to workers waiting on the results of other computations and/or transferring large amounts of data?

Comment: More information available in the dashboard. Look at the process stream first.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev: if there were waiting involved like you say, I would have expected to see the impact of this every time I execute the same dask graph. But what I see is that in some cases computations are fast and use most CPUs, and in other cases only 1 CPU is used. Often, once an execution of the graph only engages 1 CPU, then subsequent computes also only use 1 CPU (as seen in the second example).

Comment: @mdurant: do you mean the task stream? What I see there is that all 10 threads are working on a task almost all the time, but tasks take longer because only 1 CPU is engaged. What other information can get from the dashboard that could help me to isolate the issue? (By the way, I am running this in jupyterlab on jupyterhub (kubernetes))